# how come the prop is showing as undefined when it actually contains an array

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, prop

I am trying to `console.log` the updated rows (which belongs to add order line page) in the empty quotation page which is in entirely different folder and I passed the updated row as props still its showing undefined
need help!!

```
const EmptyQuotation = ({ updatedRows }) => {
  
const [cancelButton, setCancelButton] = useState(false)

const handleSavebutton = () => {
  console.log('updatedRows',updatedRows);
};
```

`EmptyQuotation` page doesn't contain `AddOrderline` component

below is the add new row function (which contains `updatedRows`)

```
// Add New Table Row
const addNewRow = (values) => {
  RepeatedTableRowIndex = parseFloat(RepeatedTableRowIndex) + 1;
  let updatedRows = [...tableRows];
  updatedRows[RepeatedTableRowIndex] = {
    index: RepeatedTableRowIndex,
    Description: [
      values.programCode,
      values.vehicleCode,
      values.description,
      values.part,
    ].join("-"),
    SaleQty: values.saleQty,
    HoursPerUnit: "",
    TotalJobHours: "",
    UnitPrice: "",
    Subtotal: "",
  };
  setRows(updatedRows);
  console.log("updatedRows", updatedRows);
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fvnq.png)

Comment: Need the full component to see what you are trying to do

Comment: You haven't posted any code which shows how `EmptyQuotation` is being used/props are passed.

Comment: Your code postings don't really explain what the issue is; please update it to show how the updatedRows prop is passed to your EmptyQuotation component.